What I have to do more to improve my regression model in r
I want to make beverage sales predicting model. I am doing regression analysis. All the column types are integer. The dimensions of the data are 15375 rows x 400 columns. The dependent variable $y$ is the beverage sale proportion.
Data is given below.

After backward elimination and changing $y$ to fit normalize hypothesis, I used this model.
reg<-lm(I(log(y+1)^0.4650181) ~ x1 + I(x2^2) + I(x3^2) + x4 + I(x5^2)...x17 ,data = train)

I think the regression model can be improved, but I don't know what I have to do more. Please give me some advice after seeing the plot(reg) output.

I've done log transformation and square root transformation of $y$.

I have specified the dimensions in your data as 15375 rows x 400 columns, as it wasn't clear from your question. You can correct that point if it is wrong.

First off, the transformation of the dependent variable is just odd. I'm guessing there is no way to meaningfully interpret the dependent variable if it is converted in this fashion, and its not clear how it improves things. If your goal is to have a normally distributed dependent variable, there are better things to consider, namely if 1) it even matters and 2) which residual distribution better works with your model given this problem. Transforming in this way often doesn't solve the problem unless you have a every specific purpose for doing it (e.g. fitting a log-log regression to achieve elasticity). Since you are dealing with a proportion that is bounded between 0 and 1, it may be better to fit a model which deals with these constraints (e.g. beta regression).
Second, you have a lot of predictors, and perhaps with a lot of data this works. If your purpose is solely prediction as the post suggests, then I suppose more variables are okay for this, but there ought to be a more principled approach than backwards selection (which is notoriously bad). You may consider alternative penalized approaches like ridge regression. LASSO, or elastic nets. Some info about those can be found here.
The many polynomial terms leave me asking for more. Are there nonlinear patterns in your data? Do the polynomials actually do a good job of fitting the data as you have here? I tend to prefer splines for nonlinear patterns of data, but more information about that point may be helpful.
